# Sending query to the same page

Tags: php

I have this form

```
<form action="index.php?store=<?php echo $_GET['store'];?>/" method="GET">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txt-fc" name="s" placeholder="Enter Product Name" />
</form>
```

The url of the current page is like this

```
index.php?store=gsStore
```

Now the problem is that when I submit the form the url becomes this

```
index.php?s=Graphics+Cards
```

Since there is no `store` in the url therefore php shows error! What I actually want is that it should submit the form without losing the `store` variable like this

```
index.php?store=gsStore&s=Graphics+Cards
```

How it is achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use hidden input element:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="store" value="<?php echo $_GET['store'];?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txt-fc" name="s" placeholder="Enter Product Name" />
</form>
```

Comment: To be honest with you... I have used this trick a lot of times using `hidden` fields... This time it didn't come up my mind. Thank you for the answer :) will accept asap time penalty finishes

Comment: You should consider escaping any unwanted HTML tag in order to avoid GET exploits.

Comment: @AlexShifu What happens if user follows the link without store parameter? I think you should handle it in the PHP and either redirect user to the default store OR put the default store parameter instead of GET['store'] in the code if it is empty. Think about it. 
Glad to hear it helps.

Comment: Ummm! You just gave a very important idea!